# Configure nginx to statically cache certain URLs

Tags: file, caching, nginx, url-rewriting, try-catch

I want to cache certain URLs in my app by looking up static files directly. However, the statically cached files may not exist, so I only want to redirect the request if the files exist. I imagine I can use try_files for this somehow, but so far I have not been successful in doing it right.

Here's what I tried:

```
location ^/(.*)/(.*)/other/stuff/(.*)/this-is-static {
  try_files /static-cache/$1/$2/$3/this-is-static @app;
}
```

`static-cache` is an internal location configured in the same file. This does not appear to work as intended. What's wrong?

The closest I've gotten is this, which rewrites every request (and thus fails when the file is not cached):

```
location ^/(.*)/(.*)/other/stuff/(.*)/this-is-static {
  rewrite ^ /static-cache/$1/$2/$3/this-is-static;
}
```

Comment: when doing regex you should start the location block with ~ `location ~ /bla(.*)bla {`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `~`?, I also used `[^/]` to avoid greedy regex

```
location ~ /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/other/stuff/([^/]*)/this-is-static {
    try_files /static-cache/$1/$2/$3/this-is-static @app;
}
location @app {
    #handle non cached files
}
```